# How do you add IMsRdpClientTransportSettings4 to MFC application - Is there a TypeLib?

Tags: winapi, com, activex, rdp

I want to add `IMsRdpClientTransportSettings4` inteface to an MFC application.  To add the `IMsRdpClientAdvancedSettings8` interface I used the visual studio `project menu / add new item` then `MFC category / MFC Class from TypeLib` and chose `Microsoft Terminal Services Active Client` (I was following a tutorial - I wouldn't have guessed that name is associated with advanced settings).

Does a TypeLib exist for adding the `IMsRdpClientTransportSettings4`?  If not, how do you do it manually?

TIA!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/imsrdpclienttransportsettings4#requirements) section in the documentation lists the type library as *"MsTscAx.dll"*.

You can verify that this DLL contains a type library by opening it in a tool like [OLE/COM Object Viewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/ole-com-object-viewer) (*oleview.exe*).

Comment: Okay, I ran that and it listed in there, but what do I choose via adding in visual studio 2022 from project menu / add new item / MFC / "MFC Class from TypeLib" ?

Comment: Select *"Implement interface from"*: *"File"*, enter the *"MsTscAx.dll"* under *"Location"*, and select the interface(s) you need under *"Available interfaces"*. That'll generate a header file with the interface definitions. I used VS 2022 Preview, things might look different on VS 2022 proper.

Comment: I see said the blind man.

Comment: There's still the odd aspect that the MFC New Item wizard generates a class description that goes through the `IDispatch` interface. While not wrong, it's still a lot more costly than accessing the interface's vtable directly (the dispatch interface is intended for scripting languages, such as VBScript). I'll have a look into the why, or how to change that when I find time.